# How to control an object with a finger in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming. I am writing a simple game (I think many people know it under the name "Ping Pong") for smartphones. A game for two people. I need the screen to be divided into two areas. Everyone within their area should be able to control the object with their finger along the x axis. Accordingly, the object changes its position only along the x axis.

[here's my game :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prtaB.png)

I was able to write this script myself:

```
Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) * new Vector2(1, 0);
Vector2 mousePosition2 = mousePosition + new Vector2(1, -4.74f);
transformPosition1.transform.position = mousePosition2;
```

This script changes the position of the object relative to the x-axis of the mouse. But I do not know how to limit its area and divide it into two players. Thank you in advance for your help. I apologize for my English. Please do not use complex language constructions in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One way would be putting one image to top half of the screen and other to bottom half and assign [EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html) to handle dragging.
2. Other way is to calculate the mouse position to see if it is within the top half or bottom half.

   ```
   Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
   float y = mousePosition .y;

   if (y > Screen.height / 2 && y < Screen.height)// top half {
   // move the top side player
   }
   if (y > 0 && y < Screen.height / 2)// bottom half {
   // move the bottom side player
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks to Alexander for a good and simple solution! While there was no answer, I found this video, which also solved my problem. I'll leave it here if anyone needs it. 

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poC3JMLQRBA&t=1388s